# SQL Server Outlier Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

I am looking for a way to perform basic outlier filtration on a column of data in SQL server.

#### Background

I have a log table that contains various actions and the times at which those actions occurred.  I am looking to retrieve some data surrounding the average time between two distinct log event types.  I'm using a simple query (using `DATEDIFF` between timestamps) to capture the time duration between those events.  Currently, I use an `AVG` function to get the average time for all paired instances of those two events occurring.

#### Problem

I would like to perform outlier filtration on the dataset prior to averaging using the following method:

```
Y is an outlier if Y < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR) 
    OR
Y is an outlier if Y > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)

Where Q1 is the first quartile boundary value, 
      Q3 is the third quartile boundary value,
      and IQR is Q3 - Q1.
```

My question is first - what is the best way to determine quartile values in SQL and second - is there a way that I can store this as it's own aggregate function to filter and then average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me presume that you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, since what you want to do requires window functions.

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select min(y) as q1, max(y) as q3, max(y) - min(y) as iqr
      from (select y,
                   row_number() over (order by y) as seqnum,
                   count(*) over (partition by null) as total
            from t
           ) t
      where seqnum = cast(total*0.25 as int) or seqnum = cast(total*0.75 as int)
     ) qs
 where (y < q1 - 1.5*iqr) or (y > q3 + 1.5*iqr)
```

Some notes on how this works.  The qs subquery is calculating the quartiles explicitly -- by sequencing the rows (by y) and taking the value that is at the rows 25% and 75% of the way through the data.  Note that the comparison compares the sequence number to the total of rows times that fraction *cast back to an integer*.

The group by just puts these values into one row, for each of calculation.  The where clause is the logic that you want to apply for exclusion.

Comment: `NTILE` has been in the product since 2005.

Comment: @MartinSmith How would you suggest using NTILE in here instead?

Comment: @mbeasley - I didn't suggest that. It was a reference to a statement in the first version of this answer that indicated this was new in 2012.

Comment: Gordon - Is there a way that I could store this in an aggregate function coupled with the `AVG` averaging function such that I can use it to get the filtered average of any dataset?

Comment: I guess more importantly, is there a way that I could set this up as a stored procedure to apply dynamically to any table / column?